# ASN.1Integer to normal integer

Tags: java, integer

My server recive an Integer using ASN.1 generated classes

```
BerInputStream in = new BerInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
           h.decode(in);
           ASN1Integer ClientNumber= h.clientInt;
            System.out.println(ClientNumber);
```

h.clientInt return an ASN.1Integer.
If the Client send 4 the output is

```
BerInteger([Universal 2])=4
```

How to cast this ASN.1Integer to an Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASN1Integer` extends `BerInteger`. [BerInteger](https://code.google.com/p/java-asn1-goose-hxzon/source/browse/trunk/chaos-in-motion/com/chaosinmotion/asn1/BerInteger.java?r=23) has a `getValue` method which returns a `long` value. This can be cast to an integer if required:

```
ASN1Integer clientNumber = h.clientInt;
int value = (int)clientNumber.getValue();
```

(Though best to use a long to achieve full precision)

Comment: thanx, but hpw it work with String ? The are no getValue, I tried this but it don't work  IA5String serverString=response1.serverString;
String serverString = (String) serverString.getBytes();

Comment: There are actually multiple implementations of `ASN1Integer`. Can you confirm that **[this](http://afinaimagem.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/desktop/JAC/src/com/turkcelltech/jac/ASN1Integer.java)** is the one you are using?

Comment: yes and your solution for ASN1Integer work perfectly but now I have a problem with the IA5String

Comment: This is a different issue. Would advise to 1) accept this answer 2) post new question with type and output values for `response1`